# How can I generate a random set of alpha only characters in coded ui test?

Tags: random, coded-ui-tests

I have used the following code to generate a random set of characters for customer last names. Today, the developers restricted last names to alpha only and now I can't figure out how to get only alpha. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
var alph = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);
var LastName = TestContext.DataRow["LastName"].ToString() + add + alph;`
```

Comment: btw, in your case you may want to use `Keyboard.SendKeys(UITestControl control, String inputValue, ModifierKeys mods)` to bypass codedUi's validation for if the text actually got set to a value. then follow up with an Assert on what the actual value of the text box. i.e. textbox prevents numbers, sent "abc123def", `Assert.AreEqual(textbox.Text,"abcdef");`

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything that doesn't match RegEx `[^a-z, A-Z]` with `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of all the letters you want, then index into them with a random number:

```
string[] letters = new string []{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
Random rand = new Random();

string theName = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    int letterIndex = rand.Next(0,4);
    theName += letters[letterIndex];
}

Console.WriteLine(theName);
```

Comment: I will give it a shot!